# Cannot make POST request to self

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get my Apps Script days-old web app to send POST data to itself. However, upon submitting the form, I get a `SAMEORIGIN` error. The weird thing is that I'm doing the exact same thing on another months-old GAS Web App with no issue...

```
<form action="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>" method="post" id="loginForm">
<div class="input"><span class="label">Password:</span> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required"></div>
<div class="input"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></div>
</form>
```

The same form is on my other web app, created a few months ago, and works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Found my error. This needs to be placed in the HTML head:

`<base target="_top">`

That way it reloads the entire page with the request, not just the iframe sandbox.